# MKMapView userLocation not showing in ipod

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, showuserlocation

i used

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

for showing blue dot (circle) on MKmapview. Its working fine in simulator. but when i tested in Ipod, its not showing. Anybody know what will be the reason ? thanks in advance

Comment: Does it show when you use Maps on the iPod touch?

Comment: blue dot circle not showing in ipod ..only in simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blue circle doesn't show in Maps either, than your local wifi networks aren't in the system (on the iPod your locationis determined by the nearest wifi ssid's). Two solutions: get them listed (not sure where you can do that) or go somewhere where it does work. In the iPhone Simulator you get a simulated location, so not so interesting that it works.

If you get the blue circle in Maps but not in your map, we can look further at it.

Comment: SkyHook is a good place to start with registering wifi networks.

Comment: thanks Johan..am getting this alert when am using Maps Iphone App, "Your location could not be determined". as u told its may be because of  the company that apple worked with on this might not has covered my area yet.. so i think i can use this way to cover my area..
http://www.352media.com/rantingandraving/rave.aspx?raveid=289&id=178

thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Is the iPod on the same, wireless network with location services enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Check if u have given the delegates --->map.delegate=SomeController;

```
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark;
```

and

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```